# Does powershell have an equivalent to popen?

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to launch a process and read the output into a variable.  Then based on the return of the command I can choose to show the full output or just a selected subset.

So to be clear, I want to launch a text based process (psexec actually) and read the output from that command (stdout, stderr, etc) into a variable rather than have it directly outputted to the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You left off some details regarding what kind of process, but I think [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/01/16/managing-processes-in-powershell.aspx) from the Powershell Team Blog has whatever you'd like to do, either from piping the executable's output somewhere or utilizing `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Now that the second option sounds like what you want to do, you can use the `ProcessStartInfo` class to feed in `true` as the `RedirectStandardOutput` property, and then read from the `StandardOutput` property of the `Process` object to do whatever you want with the output.  `StandardError` works identically.

Comment: Not sure how much clearer you want it.  I want to capture output from a command launched by powershell... like popen.  That page seems only to list ways to start processse.

Comment: Right, that example covers launching executables.  Utilize the ProcessStartInfo class, specifically the RedirectStandardOutput property to capture what you want.

Comment: Aye, just figured that out at the same time.  Any hints on reading data from a stream in powershell?

Comment: Not much, except that I forsee heavy usage of "new-object" and the System.IO namespace in your future. :)

Comment: Well, it actually seems pretty simple just a ReadToend() method on the stream.

Comment: Wow...sorry. Just read this full comment stream after posting my answer. Seems like you've got it all figured out. :)

Comment: check out the following question for the code snippet for calling [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919171/capture-exe-output-in-powershell

Answer (score 1):

As far as reading stuff into variables is concerned, you should just be able to do something like

```
$output = ps
```

This will only capture stdout, though, not the verbose, warning or error streams.  You can get the exit code of the previous command by testing the special variable `$?`.

I think a little more information would be of use to provide a more complete answer, but hopefully this is some way towards what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerShellCX) includes **Start-Process**. This actually returns a **System.Diagnostics.Process**.

```
> $proc = Start-Process pslist -NoShellExecute
```

However, while this returns the **Process** object it does not allow you to redirect the output prior to executing. To do that one can create their own process and execute it by first modifying the **ProcessStartInfo** members:

```
> $proc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
> $proc.StartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("pslist.exe")
> $proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
> $proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
> $proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
> $proc.Start()
> $proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```